# Time-aware tool or website for currency conversion

Tags: finance, currency-converter

I would like to know, say, what 1$ on January 1st, 2010 is worth in today's €.

I'm no economist, but that probably means:

- Applying "the" $-€ conversion rate that was in place *on that day*, obtaining January 1st, 2010 euros
- Adjusting that amount for inflation to convert it into euros of today's.

Something that ran offline would be preferable (any platform but Mac) to something that ran online with APIs would be preferrable to something that ran online period.

Comment: For example http://www.westegg.com/inflation/ does the inflation adjustement bit, so long as you convert *to* USD.

Comment: You won't find something that runs offline, as most currencies vary continuously in value.

Comment: @VicAche It'd just need to download past exchange and inflation rates from somewhere. Sure, while offline you wouldn't get _new_ ones, but...

Comment: Combining @badp's suggestions with http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=2010-01-01 for historical exchange rates comes close.

Comment: The wolfram developer platform can be used to write such a tool in like 3 lines of code. I did this because I needed a currency converter like this myself.